# How to make my search input dynamic so that I won't have to use any submit button or press enter after I write something in the search bar

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, ejs

I want to update my answers in the ejs file whenever the search input in changed without pressing enter.
I have used a script which bing-chat provided me but it has two problems

1. it shows results for the first few inputs i give, then I have to restart the server again
2. It is not updating results in the 'search-results' div

please provide me a solution to this

here is the user.controllers.js file's code

```
const {pool} = require('../config/database.config');
const MiniSearch = require('minisearch');
const userModels = require('../models/user.models');

const getHome = async(req, res) => {
  const searchedValue = typeof req.query.searchedValue === 'undefined'? '' : req.query.searchedValue;
  const deptFilter    = typeof req.query.deptFilter === 'undefined'? '' : req.query.deptFilter;
  const yearFilter    = typeof req.query.yearFilter === 'undefined'? '' : req.query.yearFilter;
  const fromDate      = typeof req.query.fromDate === 'undefined'? '' : req.query.fromDate;
  const toDate        = typeof req.query.toDate === 'undefined'? '' : req.query.toDate; 
  console.log('searchedValue: ' + searchedValue);
  // console.log(fromDate);
  // console.log(toDate);

  // -------------client query --------------
  const all_results = [];
  {
    const query = `select * from "users"`;
    const client = await pool.connect();
  
    await client.query(query)
      .then((result) => {
        result.rows.forEach((row) => {
          all_results.push(row);
        })
      })
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  }
  // -------------client query ends --------------
  
  const minisearch = new MiniSearch({
    fields: ['id','name', 'description','id','name', 'description', 'dept', 'year', 'fromDate', 'toDate'],
    storeFields: ['id','name', 'description', 'dept', 'year', 'fromDate', 'toDate'],
  });
  
  minisearch.addAll(all_results);
  minisearch.autoSuggest(searchedValue, { prefix: true, fuzzy: 0.2 });

  // Defining the filter criteria
  const filterCriteria = (result, filters) => {
    return Object.entries(filters).every(([key, value]) => {
      if (!value) {
        // If filter value is empty or not provided, include the result
        return true;
      } 

      console.log(key, value);
      // Check the result property against the filter value
      if(key == 'fromDate') {
        const formattedDate = userModels.formatDate(result.fromDate);
        console.log(formattedDate);
        return value <= formattedDate;
      }

      if(key == 'toDate') {
        console.log('when toDate true');
        const formattedDate = userModels.formatDate(result.toDate);
        console.log(formattedDate);

        if(value >= formattedDate) {
          // console.log('true');
          return true;
        } else {
          // console.log('false');
          return false
        };
      }

      if (result[key] === undefined || result[key] !== value) {
        return false;
      }
  
      return true;
      
    });
  };
  
  // defining the filters
  const filters = {
    dept: deptFilter,
    year: yearFilter,
    fromDate: fromDate,
    toDate: toDate  
  }

  // Extracting the searched values into results
  let results = (searchedValue) ? 
  minisearch.search(searchedValue, {
    prefix:true,
    fuzzy: 0.4,
    filter: (result) => filterCriteria(result, filters)
  })
  : all_results.filter((result) => filterCriteria(result, filters));
  

  console.log('results');
  console.log(results);

  // just putting hte results in a format that can be used in ejs 
  // in 'search_results' variable
  const search_results = results.map((result) => {
      return {
        id: result.id,
        name: result.name,
        description: result.description,
      };
    });

  console.log('search_results');
  console.log(search_results);

  // flashing the search results to be used in ejs
  if(search_results.length) {
    req.flash('search_results', search_results);
  } else {
    req.flash('search_results');
  }

  // rendering the ejs file
  res.render('../Views/user.ejs', {
    search_results: req.flash('search_results')
  });
}

const getSearchResult = async(req, res) => {

}

module.exports = {
  getHome,
  getSearchResult
}
```

and here is the user.ejs file's code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>User</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/search" method="GET">
        <h1>SEARCH HERE</h1>
        <input type="search" name="searchedValue" id="searchedValue" oninput="this.form.submit()">
        <br>
        <label for="filter">Select a filter:</label>
        <select id="deptFilter" name="deptFilter">
          <option value="" id="Department" name="Department">Department</option>
          <option value="CSE" id="CSE" name="CSE">CSE</option>
          <option value="EEE" id="EEE" name="EEE">EEE</option>
          <option value="ME" id="EEE" name="ME">ME</option>
        </select>
        <select id="yearFilter" name="yearFilter">
          <option value="" id="Year" name="Year">Year</option>
          <option value="first" id="first" name="first">First Year</option>
          <option value="second" id="second" name="second">Second Year</option>
          <option value="third" id="third" name="third">Third Year</option>
          <option value="fourth" id="fourth" name="fourth">Fourth Year</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <label for="fromDate"> From </label>
        <input type="date" id="fromDate" name="fromDate">
        <label for="toDate"> To </label>
        <input type="date" id="toDate" name="toDate">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
    </form> 
      
    <script>
      // Get references to the input fields
      const searchedValueInput = document.querySelector('#searchedValue');
      const deptFilterInput = document.querySelector('#deptFilter');
      const yearFilterInput = document.querySelector('#yearFilter');
      const fromDateInput = document.querySelector('#fromDate');
      const toDateInput = document.querySelector('#toDate');

      // Listen for changes in the input fields
      searchedValueInput.addEventListener('input', updateSearchResults);
      deptFilterInput.addEventListener('change', updateSearchResults);
      yearFilterInput.addEventListener('change', updateSearchResults);
      fromDateInput.addEventListener('change', updateSearchResults);
      toDateInput.addEventListener('change', updateSearchResults);

      // Update the search results when any of the input fields change
      function updateSearchResults() {
        // Get the current values of the input fields
        const searchedValue = searchedValueInput.value;
        const deptFilter = deptFilterInput.value;
        const yearFilter = yearFilterInput.value;
        const fromDate = fromDateInput.value;
        const toDate = toDateInput.value;

        // Send an asynchronous request to your server to get the search results
        fetch(`/search?searchedValue=${searchedValue}&deptFilter=${deptFilter}&yearFilter=${yearFilter}&fromDate=${fromDate}&toDate=${toDate}`)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => {
            // Get a reference to the search results container
            const searchResultsContainer = document.querySelector('#search-results');

            // Clear any existing search results
            searchResultsContainer.innerHTML = '';

            // Check if there are any search results
            if (data.search_results.length > 0) {
              // Loop through the search results and create an element for each one
              data.search_results.forEach(result => {
                const resultElement = document.createElement('div');
                resultElement.innerHTML = `
                  <h1>${result.id}</h1>
                  <h2>${result.name}</h2>
                  <h3>${result.description}</h3>
                `;
                searchResultsContainer.appendChild(resultElement);
              });
            } else {
              // If there are no search results, display a message
              searchResultsContainer.innerHTML = '<h1>No results found</h1>';
            }
          });
      }
    </script>

    <div id="search-results" name="search-results">
      <% if(search_results.length > 0) { %>
        <% search_results.forEach((result) => { %>
          <div>
            <h1><%= result.id %></h1>
            <h2><%= result.name %></h2>
            <h3><%= result.description %></h3>
          </div>
        <% }) %>
      <% } else { %>
        <h1> <%= 'No results found' %> </h1>
      <% } %> 
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

I am expecting a solution where I can search data and make it show in the page just by typing in the search bar without pressing anything

Comment: How do you expect to know when the user has completed typing the search term? If the user's search term has multiple characters you may do number of characters - 1 unnecessary searches. That is a search term of 10 characters may do 9 unnecessary searches, and 50 characters up to 49 unnecessary searches. This may be fine if the potential search set in memory cached but not so if you need to access the database each time.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use [javascript DOM EventListener](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp)

JavaScript:

```
var inputElement = document.getElementById("myInput");
inputElement.addEventListener("input", handleInput);
function handleInput(event) {
      var inputValue = event.target.value;
      console.log("Input Value: " + inputValue);
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
  <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="What are you Looking For ?">
</body>
```

You can now process the data inside the function handleInput, and update your UI according to the search data.

Comment: I guess I got the primary part, as I can show data to my ejs file just when I type in the search bar, by using the eventListener, really thank you

But how can I use the 'minisearch' package inside that script tag inside the ejs file?

Please let me know @xPyth

Comment: or how can I link the backend 'getHome' function from the user.controller every time i change the value? is that possible